# Responsive application with vanilla css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build an app that looks  great on all devices but I'm having an issue with the responsiveness, actually I have a dought for what should I do. so here is what I'm thinking about:

1- If I build the app using the device toolbar which means I start with a media querie of 320px up to 1440px

like this :

[image]

and that's what I did actually and everything is going Ok at least that's what I thought but when I use the viewport width ( increasing, decreasing it) I see some unexpected results

this is on 605px viewport width:

[image]

I built this app with absolute positioning and I applied a position relative to the img in the background, maybe this is bad practice I know , please note that the app looks great on all devices that the device toolbar offers me.

some of my friends adviced me to use a framework and get rid of all these headaches but really I wanna practice vanilla CSS very well please consider that this is my first app and I'm doing my best to make it look great on all devices

so my question is:

1. should I leave it like this because logically If it looks ok on the
   devices like Iphone 6 ... (the devices that the device toolbar
   offers me) I don't need to address the viewport width issue.
2. or should I use a framework and I don't like this solution I know
   it's feasible and as I told you I wanna practice vanilla css.
3. or should I use another technologie like flexbox or grid system and
   this is the hardest solution I think because I'm gonna rebuild the
   entire app, but it's ok.

and the last thing I wanna ask about is: is there anythings should I be aware of  in my future projects especially if I'm working with vanilla CSS

Comment: I don't exactly see what's wrong... Is it the grey area at the bottom?

Comment: You can also tell a bit more about what units are you using for styling. Are those relative units like `%` that change based on screen width?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congrats on building your first app!

1) When posting questions on Stackoverflow, it is always helpful to provide either an example of your code directly in your post, and/or to include a link to a running version of your code on a site like jsfiddle.net, JSbin.com, codepen.io, etc.

2) For most responsive apps, there are almost always a couple of widths where things do not look exactly perfect. These points are usually right before/after a breakpoint transition.

3) In general, you don't want to use position `relative` or `absolute` for handling page layout. There are a number of situations where they can be helpful, but I think its safe to say that they should **never** be the first thing you reach for when trying to create the layout of a page.

4) Right now, the best way to handle page layout with regular CSS -- no library -- is probably Flexbox because of its versatility and adoption of all major browsers. I highly recommend you learn it and become familiar with it.

5) There is nothing wrong with using a library for general page structure stuff. Because of its use with a ton of companies, I highly recommend you become familiar with Bootstrap -- specifically its grid framework. If you do go this route, read the rules for certain things very carefully. For example, I cannot tell you how many people have their apps look screwed up because they don't follow the cardinal rule of Bootstrap's grid system: The only children of a `row` should be `col`. Say that 10 times.

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Also would mention that if you only want to kinda get familiar with Flexbox and other things without using a full-blown Framework like Bootstrap, you could just include the [Bootstrap Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/borders/) to apply general CSS with a clear name... that way you can use only what you think its needed without dealing with the full library, and in time you'll get familiar with how properties work and how you can mix them! :)